# MySQL variable table naming creation

Tags: mysql

I am creating a database for a collection of servers for minecraft, and the way I have it set up, I want a table to be created for each server as it is added. At the moment, I have everything working except for the fact that i cannot get the tables that are being created to contain the IP address. I want the table to be something like [IP]_Players where the [IP] is replaced by the actual IP address, which will be send through the function that it is being created through. Here is what I have so far:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `minecraft`.`AddServer` (ip Text)
BEGIN
DECLARE play TEXT;
DECLARE tran TEXT;
SET play = ip + '_Players';
SET tran = ip + '_Transactions';
INSERT INTO `minecraft`.`Server_Data` (`Server_IP`) VALUES (ip);
CREATE TABLE `minecraft`.play (
  `Player` TEXT NOT NULL ,
  `Balance` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT 100 ,
  `Warnings` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `Offences` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `Player_UNIQUE` (`Player` ASC) );
CREATE  TABLE `minecraft`.tran (
  `Time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
  `Player` TEXT NOT NULL ,
  `Destination` TEXT NOT NULL ,
  `Amount` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
  `Description` TEXT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Time`) );
END
```

Instead of creating it as 192.168.001.107_Players when 
`CALL minecraft.AddServer('192.168.001.107');` 
is preformed, it creates a table called `play`.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was playing around and got this to work.  Note that you cannot have periods in a table name.  So you may want to use the REPLACE function to replace the periods with underscores for example.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `minecraft`.`AddServer` (ip Text)
BEGIN
DECLARE play varchar(500);
DECLARE STMT varchar(500);
SET play = CONCAT(ip, '_Players');
SET @sql_stmt = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE minecraft.', play, ' (
  `Player` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `Balance` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT 100 ,
  `Warnings` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `Offences` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `Player_UNIQUE` (`Player` ASC) );');
PREPARE STMT FROM @sql_stmt;
EXECUTE STMT;
END$$

Delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use prepared statements I guess

[SQL Syntax Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).